# Calculate the distance to a point on an arbitrary axis

Tags: java, math, vector

Given a  simple 2D vector (represented with a point and a direction), how do you find the distance to another point, but only in the direction given?

For example, say I have points `start: (1.0, 0.0)` and `end: (2.0, 0.0)`. If I get the distance from start to end along the x-axis, the result will be 1, but it is 0 when checking along the y-axis. I need an equation that would work for any direction. For our purposes we'll say the direction is simply radians.

Comment: What equation(s) have you used so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the direction angle to a vector (adapt accordingly if your angle should be interpreted differently):

```
dir = (cos(angle), sin(angle))
```

Then, project both points onto this vector and find the difference as their distance along this vector:

```
distance = dot(dir, end) - dot(dir, start)
         = dir.x * (end.x - start.x) + dir.y * (end.y - start.y)
```

Given your examples:

```
start = (1, 0)
end = (2, 0)
dir = (1, 0)
=> distance = 1 * (2 - 1) + 0 * (0 - 0) = 1
dir = (0, 1)
=> distance = 0 * (2 - 1) + 1 * (0 - 0) = 0
```

For this to work, `dir` has to be a unit vector.

Answer (score 1):

You need [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Suppose the position vectors of the points that you have are `(a,b,c)` and `(p,q,r)`.

Distance vector will be `(p-a, q-b, r-c)`.

Now the suppose direction vector is (x, y, z) in which you need component of distance calculated previously.

To calculate that we need dot product of distance and direction vectors.

Which can be calculated as `Sum(x1*x2) = X1*X2 *Cos(A)`

or `Sum(distanceX1 * directionX1) = |distance| * |direction| * Cos(A)`

```
|vector| = magnitude of vector = sqrt(Sum(x1*x1))
```

So dot product is `x*(p-a) + y*(q-b) + z*(r-c)`

The distance that we need is the `distance * Cos(A)` so we have to divide the the dot product with magnitude of direction vector.

That is `( x*(p-a) + y*(q-b) + z*(r-c) ) / sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)`

That is the result.